# Automator Help: take Fixed-Position Screenshot, click "Next Page" and Repeat (that's it!)

Tags: applescript, automator, screen-capture

I don't know code which is really embarrassing for simple tasks like this one.  All I'm trying to do is to make a Quick Action in Automator for this:

1. take a screenshot based on two fixed points
2. click a "next" button in an app (in my case; Kindle for Mac)
3. Repeat X times

Caveat (if relevant): my screenshots capture in JPG format (not PNG).

Though my "watch me do" was *not* successful, the recording process did capture me depressing the app's page-advance button which I see is called "Next Page."

A workaround would be to use CliClick to push the advance button, if which I already have installed if "Next Page" might not work for whatever reason.  The repeating screenshot would be a pre-defined pair of coordinates based on upper-left and lower-right (which I can get via CMD+SHIFT+4).

Thanks so much in advance!  Any method to pull this off in Automator is fine by me.  Cheers!

EDIT 1: added code for @ankii below here
EDIT 2: deleted what was added in EDIT 1 (no longer relevant)

Comment: the cliclick is what I was about to recommend too. Can you upload: **1** Open you watch me do in automator. **2** select the step where it clicks the next button, so that its highlighted. **3** press command + c **4** Open Script Editor.app and paste. **5** upload the script that you get. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378287/313842

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this! I pasted the resulting code above in the original post, so it would display as it did when I pasted it in Script Editor.  Thanks so much for helping me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kindle** is not **AppleScript** scriptable in that it does not contain an **AppleScript** *dictionary* within its *application bundle*; however it is, within limits, using **System Events** and **UI Scripting**. Note though that with **UI Scripting** one must not use the system for other things while the *script* is running as **Kindle** needs to remain *frontmost* while the *script* is running.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, tested under **macOS High Sierra** took screen shots of the first 5 pages of the **BASH Reference Manual**:

```applescript
set saveToLocation to POSIX path of (path to pictures folder)
set bookName to "BASH Reference Manual"
set pageCount to 5

set pathFileName to saveToLocation & bookName

tell application "Kindle" to activate

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell window 1 of application process "Kindle" to ¬
        set {position, size} to {{693, 66}, {1006, 1089}}

repeat with i from 1 to pageCount

    set shellCMD to ¬
        "screencapture -R837,124,770,994 -t jpg '" & ¬
        pathFileName & " - Page " & ¬
        i & " of " & pageCount & ".jpg'"

    do shell script shellCMD
    delay 1.5
    --  # Press right-arrow key.
    tell application "System Events" to key code 124
    delay 1.5

end repeat
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: I'm super excited to try this.  Will report back asap (within 60 min).  Sorry for the novice question, but which set of four numbers are for my screenshot corners?  I assume these are the ones just after "screencapture" but the "R" throws me off.  Again, I don't know code unfortunately.  Thanks in advance for your time.  Can't wait to try this out!

Comment: @Ryan, In **Terminal** run `screencapture --help` and near the bottom you'll see: `-R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect` Also the e.g., `set {position, size} to {{693, 66}, {1006, 1089}}` can be obtained using `tell application "System Events" to get {position, size} of window 1 of application process "Kindle"`

Comment: Thanks! I'll run this command but must advise that this sounds over my head a little.  I should clarify my desire: to *manually* set the screen-capture coordinates.  This is because I want the images to be cropped to within the "page" edges of the displayed ebook pages as they advance--instead of screenshots of the entire Kindle app window.  Sorry if I read that wrong.  "I know not what I do" is the understatement here, in my case ;)

Comment: @Ryan, I use the `{position, size} of window 1 of application process "Kindle"` as an example to do just that; however, it's the `-R<x,y,w,h>` that is being captured and for me it was just the page of the document, not the _window_ itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Everything works splendidly except for the lower-right coordinates of the image crop, which is beyond where it needs to be.  As mentioned in OP, I'm using crosshairs for x/y via CMD+SHIFT+4.  I'm using upper-left as first set of values, and this one works, but lower-right now is instead picking a position that is instead equal to the bottom of the Kindle app window, and about a half inch beyond it to the right.  Still can't figure out what's causing this.

Comment: @Ryan, I press **⇧⌘4**, move the _cross-hair_ cursor to the top left of the page, not the window, and use that for `x, y,` and then move it to the lower right of the page, not the window, and use what I get for the `w, h` and it work perfectly.

Comment: LOL.  Pulling my hair out trying to identify what is causing this.  No luck still.  I've been doing exactly as you describe from the get-go, but that said; surely the problem is something stupid at my end that I just can't see yet.  Can you check my work though; here's your code, modified only with coordinates as I recall: https://bit.ly/2AiKzzl   The integers are as follow: https://bit.ly/2AvtIJo   When I run the script however, I get this: https://bit.ly/3dPUMSa    (thanks again so much for helping me through this!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109224/discussion-between-ryan-and-user3439894).